# Can I delete /etc/nologin without ill effects?

Tags: 14.04, login

`/etc/nologin` is a softlink which points to `/var/lib/initscripts/nologin` and `/var/lib/initscripts/nologin` does not exist.

This is causing a problem for my backup process which uses `gsutil`, a Google Storage application.

If I delete `/etc/nologin`, what will happen?

Using Ubuntu 14.04.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [`man 5 nologin`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man5/nologin.5.html):

```
If  the  file  /etc/nologin exists and is readable, login(1) will allow
access only to root.  Other users will be shown the  contents  of  this
file and their logins will be refused.
```

Since your `nologin` isn't readable, it might as well not exist at all. You can delete the symlink.